# OpenLayers 4 can´t reproject JSON file

Tags: openlayers

I load a set of JSON points from my server, the points are stored in EPSG:32720, which is UTM 20S, and also for testing the same points are stored in EPSG:4326 coordinates.

Using OpenLayers 3.8.2, I load the two files and can see how the points of EPSG:32720 are reprojected and perfect match drawing one circle inside the EPSG:4326 points.

But when use OpenLayers 4 the reprojection fails, the points are displayed in another country.  The documentation of version 4 is little different to version 3. 
OL version 4 apidoc.

openlayers.org-en-latest-apidoc-ol.format.GeoJSON.html

OL version 3.8.2 apidoc.

openlayers.org-en-v3.8.2-apidoc-ol.format.GeoJSON.html

The problem is that I try 4 options:

```
     proj4.defs("EPSG:32720","+proj=utm +zone=20 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");     
    var sourceProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32720');

    1) var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection: sourceProj});
    2) var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:32720'});

    3)var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:32720'});
    4)var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:32720', featureProjection: 'EPSG:32720'});

     var vectorLayer32720 = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({            
                url: '/static/centroids32720.geojson',            
                format: UTMFormat
            }),
        style: stylePointsBlue    
       });
```

Only the 1 and 2 work with OL 3.8.2, but can figure what is wrong? I make two plunker samples one with 3.8.2 and the other with version 4.

Version 3.8.2 https://plnkr.co/edit/RNE48KkEKqiAnAd0Ssu2?p=preview

Version 4 https://plnkr.co/edit/DvwImnvi8looJRZYOjB6?p=preview

Someone can tell me what is wrong in the version 4?